# Blender Weight Painting is now not working

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

So basically, I have a rig that I'm trying to set up as a test rig for future projects, and whenever I try and set automatic weights the leg bones don't influence the right areas of the mesh.

It's supposed to look like this.

[image]

Instead, the leg bones aren't influencing the correct legs, so it turns out like this:
[image]
[image]

Any help I can get would be great, as I can't understand the issue.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6336" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6336/)

Comment: it looks like there are several problems, first you need to apply the mirror modifier, then bend a bit the armature knees in Edit mode, put the foot controller head on the exact same place as the lower leg tail, symmetrize the armature, in Pose mode change the lower leg Pole Angle so it stays as it is in Edit mode, maybe delete the foot constraint and parent it to the IK controller, then reparent... it is still not good, it happens, so use the Weight Paint mode to correct everything...

Comment: Alright sounds good! Thanks for the Help!

Comment: also maybe put some hip and shoulder bones, it might help to make a better rigging